# How to schedule a Penatho job on the Skybot scheduler?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, skybot

I could not see any reference to the Pentaho on the Skybot documentation. Is there  a way to schedule Pentaho transformations and jobs on the Skybot? I have tried creating agents and referring to the file path but nothing is working! Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For executing or scheduling in Pentaho, you need to have Pentaho installed in your system. If you are using Linux system, first of all install Pentaho DI in your system. Once you have done that make use of the Skybot schedular. Point the `Kitchen.sh` or `Pan.sh` file of pentaho DI and the files you need to schedule/execute. You can take help of this link:
[How to schedule Pentaho Kettle transformations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943748/how-to-schedule-pentaho-kettle-transformations)

If all is done you can execute a transformation. Skybot needs OS and Pentaho to execute/schedule a job. The same goes with Windows schedular or any other scheduling tool.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple. Just use the CLI tools to start your job. Kitchen I believe runs jobs. Pan will run transformations.

Here's the documentation for kitchen. It's very straight forward.

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation

Comment: I am not asking about running in kettle. The question is about skybot. Read carefully

Comment: Read carefullyer? I'm talking about running CLI jobs from skybot to run kitchen. That's how I would do it anyway but I'm not a skybot expert by any means. Is there built in integration?